# redux form : Invalid prop `form` of type `object`

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

When I use redux form, get the follow error. There is a [object Object] key in state tree form, in the picture, category_edit key is generated by call `initialize` function with me.

`` Failed prop type: Invalid prop `form` of type `object` supplied to `Form(CategoryEdit)`, expected `string`. ``

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because `reduxForm` expects to receive a settings object with `form: "string"` where string is your form name. According to the error, you passed an object to the form attribute in your settings, e.g. `form: { ... }`. If you can show your form code I could point to an exact fix.

Comment: @Honpery if the answer helped you, make sure to mark it as answered. If you found a different answer, make sure to post it yourself so that others from the community would be informed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

@Deividas Karžinauskas had it right, but his answer wasn't accepted for some reason. Setting `form: {...}` to an object instead of a string is where the problem is occurring. Removing it for me got rid of the error.
For a more hands on example:

**Erroneous code:**

```
export default connect(
  state => ({ ...state.lotOperation, form: state.lotOperationForm }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch))(LotOperationIndex)
```

**Solution**

```
export default connect(
  //notice here i'm not setting "form: {..}" to an object anymore.
  state => ({ ...state.lotOperation }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch))(LotOperationIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, when use form component, don't input props. for example:

```
@reduxForm({
    form: 'demo'
})
class Demo extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <form>
                <Field component="input" label="name" name="name"></Field>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Demo {...this.props}></Demo>); // !!==> remove this.props.
    }
}
```

The reason will be complete later... I will find.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding Honpery's answer to their own question and expanding upon it a little bit. It appears that if you pass a prop to your form component named 'form', it gets all confused.

So, for example:

```
<ContactForm
   form={this.props.form}
/>
```

is going to end in sadness. Changing it to:

```
 <ContactForm 
    formDetails={this.props.form}
 />
```

gets rid of that weird error/issue.